# Hölder's inequality for functions of multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, holder-inequality

I have one question about the Hölder's inequality.
We know that the functions in the continuous Holder inequality are f(x) and g(x). If the function were changed to f (x, y) and g (x, y) would the result still hold?
$\int_\Omega f(x,y)g(x,y)dxdy\leq(\int_\Omega |f(x,y)|^pdxdy)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\int_\Omega |g(x,y)|^qdxdy)^{\frac{1}{q}}$

Comment: It doesn't matter if $x$ is one-dimensional or a vector. Just go through the proof and you readily notice this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure does, and in fact the inequality generalizes to arbitrary measure spaces.